# Why do I get a blank page on wordpress after saving a post (after installing global custom fields)

Tags: wordpress

I just installed Global custom field just as shown here http://digwp.com/2009/09/global-custom-fields-take-two/

Basically I added this on my themes/themename/functions.php:

```
<?php

//Custom Theme Settings
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_gcf_interface');

function add_gcf_interface() {
    add_options_page('Global Custom Fields', 'Global Custom Fields', '8', 'functions', 'editglobalcustomfields');
}

function editglobalcustomfields() {
  // the html form (too long to bother you with)
}
    ?>
```

Now when I save posts I get a blank page. The post does get saved though.

Can you help in any way?

I get these two errors

```
Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in/www/newBlogs/w.sandbox/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2722

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /www/newBlogs/w.sandbox/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/functions.php:548) in/www/newBlogs/w.sandbox/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 881
```

Thanks

Comment: does commenting out `add_action()` cause it to work properly again?

Comment: it does not. it just removes the entire thing from the admin menu

Comment: Then it is something else causing your problem... the `add_action()` calls `add_gcf_interface()` which in turn adds the page containing the form that is generated by `editglobalcustomfields()`. If you comment out the action and still have a problem, then blank page is being caused elsewhere. Did you check your PHP error log?